# Put CalDav Events to Calendar in PHP

Tags: php, request, push, caldav

We are attempting to put a calendar event into a caldav calendar account (Kerio Connect) following a solution posted here: http://trentrichardson.com/2012/06/22/put-caldav-events-to-calendar-in-php/

When executing the script, the script fails at: `curl_init();`

The author suggests using `fsockopen`.

Has anyone had success pushing a calendar event via PHP to a caldav calendar account, be it Google Cal or Kerio Connect?

I am a PHP beginner, thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the sample from the website, you have to define some important values first, or replace their occurence in the code snippet.

I use the sample from the website to add events to an egroupware calendar, so the URI might be different depending on the way your calendar will be accessed via CalDAV/GroupDAV

```
$account['user'] = 'your-user';
$account['pass'] = 'password';
$account['uri'] = 'http://www.domain.com/egroupware/groupdav.php/'.$account['user'].'/calendar';
```